# knockout image binding in mvc

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, knockout.js

I develop the mvc application. Now i have to do image bind using knockout.js, I tried to bind for get image from database in front page. But image is not showing. below i give my image bind code. please check my code and correct. can anyone please help ???

**My Code**

```
<div data-bind="with: backgroundimage">

<section data-bind="style:{background:'url(attr:{src: VirtualPath})'} img width='2080' height='1362' alt=''" >

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one, If you use List of Object you should use Only First object to print using knockout if condition.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: backgroundimage">
            <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
            <section data-bind="style: { background:' url('+VirtualPath+') repeat-x'  }" style="min-height: 880px; width:100%;">
</section>
            <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set the background image for the section using knockout by doing the following.

```
<!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->

<div data-bind="with: backgroundimage">

<section data-bind="style: { background: 'url(' + path  + ')'}" >

</section>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.backgroundimage = {
        path : 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.png?v=204b1e0e421b'
    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Please find the working fiddle here.
http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/jko1nj8p/

If you want to set the path to the image dynamically, pass the path to the viewmodel.